# XUnit share context without constructor injection

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

I am trying to share context between all tests. I've found [this beautiful tutorial how it can be done through xunit](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context).

So I've created database fixture to be shared between all tests like the above tutorial said:

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    string Read();
}

public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable, IDatabase
{
    public DatabaseFixture()
    {
        Db = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");

        // ... initialize data in the test database ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // ... clean up test data from the database ...
    }

    public SqlConnection Db { get; private set; }
    public string Read()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And:

```
[CollectionDefinition("Database collection")]
public class DatabaseCollection : ICollectionFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{
    // This class has no code, and is never created. Its purpose is simply
    // to be the place to apply [CollectionDefinition] and all the
    // ICollectionFixture<> interfaces.
}
```

And shared fixture looks like this:

```
[Collection("Database collection")]
public class DatabaseBaseClass
{
    IDatabase _fixture;

    public DatabaseBaseClass(DatabaseFixture fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
    }
}
```

So far, so good, it works perfectly. However, I have **more than 300 classes and what I have to
do is to write this constructor initialization in more than 300 classes of tests**:

```
public class PersonTests : DatabaseBaseClass
{
    protected PersonTests(DatabaseFixture fixture)
        : base(fixture)
    {}
}
```

My question is  how is it possible to avoid to write the above constructor in more than 300 classes of tests? Is it possible? Maybe is there more simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create static field and share it across all derived classes like this:

```
[Collection("Database collection")]
public class DatabaseBaseClass
{
    protected static IDatabase _fixture = new DatabaseFixture();
}
```

And then there is no need to inject dependencies in constructor of all child classes.